# Concluding that the Poisson kernel is indeed the Cauchy distribution?

Tags: pr.probability, cv.complex-variables, probability-distributions, brownian-motion

See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/221823/poisson-kernel-ex-y-textexp-i-theta-x-t-theta-y-t-ei-theta-x).

> Let $d = 2$, and consider the domain $D = \mathbb{H}$, the upper half-plane. Let $W_t = (X_t, Y_t)$. We see that for any $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$ and any $t \ge 0$, we have$$E^{(x, y)}\text{exp}\{i\theta X_t - \theta Y_t\} = e^{i\theta x - \theta y}.$$

And [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/221889/poisson-kernel-expectation-an-absolute-value-comes-in).

> It follows that for $x$, $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$ and $y > 0$,$$E^{(x, y)} e^{i\theta X_\tau} = e^{i\theta x - |\theta|y}.$$

My question is, how do we use Fourier inversion to calculate the density of the random variable $X_\tau$, to conclude that the Poisson kernel is indeed the Cauchy distribution?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/221646/poisson-kernel-is-the-cauchy-distribution-reference?rq=1

Comment: This is a homework exercise --- please do not respond